# This query is failing silently and I cant understand why - Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I have posted yesterday the same question and it got closed, so before closing this one as well can someone please tell me if this is the right place to ask questions related to code problems that we have? Or am I suppose to post my question somewhere else?!

I have this query that I am trying to execute from my `React-Native` code but it fails **SILENTLY**(Doug yesterday said they don't fail silently but obviously this does):

```
    let refA = db().collection('myCollection').doc(this.state.currentUser).collection('privat').doc('privat');  //it executes this line of code but never goes to next step `.get()`

refA.get() //it never reaches here when debugging
    .then(doc => {
        console.log("Data fetched from myCollection:", doc.data());
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error:", error);
    })
```

This query seems fine to me but maybe there is something wrong that I don't see. Please let me know if you know what's going on here!

Comment: "obviously it does" There is nothing obvious about that for us, unless you actually show us the exact way to reproduce this. I run code very similar to yours on a daily basis and have *never* seen code that builds a `DocumentReference` fail without an exception being thrown.

Comment: Is `this.state.currentUser` a string, or an object? Should it be `this.state.currentUser.uid` instead?

Comment: Also, what is `db()`? Shouldn't it be `db.collection()...`?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I was doing a mistake by passing an object so no i am doing it properly `this.state.currentUser.uid` but there is another problem, I cant fetch anything, after it hits the line .get().then() it skips everything else, so it doesnt go inside the .then() callback thus I am not able to see if it actually fetching something or not, it doesnt catch any error neither!

Comment: @MichaelBleigh you are right,  I fixed that, check the other problem I mentioned on the above comment.